# Allow different formats of get parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on a website where the URL structures are like `www.example.com/Test/Page`

It was not built with a framework and I can't really go through editing the whole application.

I would like to pass GET parameters like `www.example.com/Test/Page?id=1&q=3` etc...

I can't really do that now and I believe it's because of these rules in the htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&search=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/print/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&search=$2&print=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&search=$2&section=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&search=$2&section=$3&query=$4 [L]
```

Any idea how can I edit this in order to accept both formats of the GET paramters? Thanks

Comment: No sure if I understood what you want correctly; but it sounds like you might just need the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) to append the original query string parameters (if there were any), in addition to the new ones your rewriting generates.

Comment: Where applicable, add the `QSA` flag like so: `[L,QSA]`

Comment: this worked. Thanks! I guess I need one of you to create an answer so I can approve it.